# How do I disable "Use my local drafts folder" by default?

Tags: group-policy

When users open files to edit them on my SharePoint 2010 install I would like to force the dialog box that opens to **uncheck** the "Use my local drafts folder" box by default and prevent the user from changing this.  Can it be done?  How?

Alternatively that dialog box can be eliminated altogether as long as I can set every user to never use their local drafts folder by default.

**Edit:** I should have specified this earlier, but I would like to force this change across the entire network through AD or group policy or from the back-end of SharePoint itself.  I am aware that I can use Word or Excel to change the default for any Office file, but I would like to take the option away from my users altogether for all files.

**Edit 2:** We're currently using Office 2007 with no immediate plans to move to 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Office 2010:**

This can be set using [group policy templates](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=64b837b6-0aa0-4c07-bc34-bec3990a7956&displaylang=en):

- **Category:** Microsoft Office Document Cache
- **Policy:** Check-out to local disk
- **Associated Registry Key:** software\policies\microsoft\office\common\offline\options
- **Registry Value Name:** UseLocalDrafts
- **Registry Value:** 0

**Office 2007:**

Set the following entry in the registry using group policy:

- **Key:** HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Options
- **Registry Value Name:** Local
- **Registry Value:** 0 (DWORD)

Comment: I can't remember if this feature existed for Office 2007 but if it did, you should find it at the same place in those administrative templates.

Comment: We are still using Office 2007 in my office, so I'll have to see if this method still works for us.  I'll be sure to check back and let you know!  :)

Comment: We can't find anything in GP for Office 2007 that matches what you're referencing in your answer.  :(

Comment: @JonnyP: I've updated the answer with a registry setting that should fix the issue for you.

Comment: Great, we'll try this out next week and I'll let you know.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the "Use my local drafts folder" option to be unchecked by default:

1. Open Office Word.
2. Click on the Office button.
3. Click on 'Word Options'.
4. Click on  'Save' in the left menu.
5. Under the 'Offline editing options...' section select 'The web server' instead of 'The server drafts location on this computer'.
6. Click 'OK' twice.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.  I've edited my question to better reflect what I want since I wasn't very clear originally.

Answer (score 1):

To save others the effort, here is the contents for a .reg file, just copy and paste:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Make 'Use my local drafts folder' un-ticked by
; default when checking out a document from sharepoint.

; Microsoft Office 2010+
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Options]
"UseLocalDrafts"=dword:00000000

; Microsoft Office 2007
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Options]
"Local"=dword:00000000
```